# How would I convert this Python Script to PowerShell?

Tags: python, powershell

Im really struggling trying to figure out how I'm supposed to translate a Python script to powershell.

The code is:

```
list_files = ['DC-JAN-2017.xlsx', 'DC-FEB-2017.xlsx', 'DC-MAR-2017.xlsx','DC-APR-2017.xlsx', 'DC-MAY-2017.xlsx', 'DC-JUN-2017.xlsx','DC-JUL-2017.xlsx', 'DC-AUG-2017.xlsx', 'DC-SEP-2017.xlsx','DC-OCT-2017.xlsx', 'DC-NOV-2017.xlsx', 'DC-DEC-2017.xlsx']

zip_loop = zip(list_files, [i[3:6] for i in list_files])

# Final report DataFrame
df_report = pd.DataFrame()

for file_name, month in zip_loop:
    # Import and Clean Data
    df_clean = clean(file_raw, month)
    # Build Monthly report
    df_month = process_month(df_clean, month)
    # Merge with previous Months report
    if df_report.empty
        df_report = df_month
    else:
        df_report = df_report.merge(df_month, on = 'index')
        
# Save Final Report

df_report.to_excel('Final Report.xlsx')
```

What i've tried so far

```
$list_files = ['DC-JAN-2017.xlsx', 'DC-FEB-2017.xlsx', 'DC-MAR-2017.xlsx','DC-APR-2017.xlsx', 'DC-MAY-2017.xlsx', 'DC-JUN-2017.xlsx',
             'DC-JUL-2017.xlsx', 'DC-AUG-2017.xlsx', 'DC-SEP-2017.xlsx','DC-OCT-2017.xlsx', 'DC-NOV-2017.xlsx', 'DC-DEC-2017.xlsx']
$zip_loop = $zip($list_files, [$i[3:6] for $i in $list_files])

# Final report DataFrame
$df_report = $pd.DataFrame()

for $file_name, $month in $zip_loop:
    # Import and Clean Data
    $df_clean = clean($file_raw, $month)
    # Build Monthly report
    $df_month = process_month($df_clean, $month)
    # Merge with previous Months report
    if $df_report.empty
        $df_report = $df_month
    else:
        $df_report = $df_report.merge($df_month, on = 'index')
        
# Save Final Report
$df_report.to_excel('Final Report.xlsx')
```

I'm not too sure what the "in", "on", statements is supposed to be in powershell.

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far and where, specifically, you're stuck.

Comment: I'm confused on how to convert the structure into powershell, like how to convert in statements, def statements, zip_loop = zip(list_files, [i[3:6] for i in list_files]).

Comment: It looks like you simply prepended `$` to each identifier in the Python code, which obviously does _not_ result in valid PowerShell code.

Comment: On behalf of non python savvy people like me, can you explain what the code should do ?